# Is there a way to create a ListView/RecycleView with an angle?

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, angle

I think that the best way to explain what I mean is to show an image.

I would like to create the following screen, As you can see it's a score screen that at the lower part of it there is a list of players that received the best scores, I want this list to be with an angle on it, and no straight as the screen it's self, as shown in the image:

[image]

Does anyone have tips on how this could be done?

Answer (score 4):

hello Emil Adz i think  this is good que you should check this 
from xml side

> android:rotation="60"

from java side

```
listview.setRotation(60)
```

or u may use this link

https://github.com/rongi/rotate-layout

hope it help you.

Answer (score 3):

try with this thing :

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:rotation="30"/>
```

rotation will surely help you

Answer (score 3):

I tried basic transformation can be done easily by rotation and position.

```html
recyclerView.setRotation(-20);
recyclerView.setY(150);
recyclerView.setX(20);
```

This is what we get by this simple positions and rotations.[image]

I think you can customize positions as per your requirements by this only.

Answer (score 1):

In `onCreate()` Try this :

```
Listview listview = (listview) findViewById(R.id.listView);
listview.setRotation(60); // Change how much as you want
```